# How to remove 'k' option when converting ANTLR 3 grammar to ANTLR 4

Tags: parsing, antlr4, antlr3

The token lookahead option is gone in ANTLR 4, so ...
This is the ANTLR 3 code:

```
declarations: // Order is important here.
    ( options { k = 3; }: DECLARE_SYMBOL identifier (variable_declaration | condition_declaration))*
        cursor_declaration* handler_declaration*
;
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `k` option. It was used to tell the parser generator the necessary lookahead. The new ALL(*) algorithm in ANTLR4 doesn't require this setting anymore as it can dynamically use any required lookahead (in theory even unlimited).